# How to format a date field in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having a problem in mysql query, I have date saved in database in this format :

> Wed, 26 Oct 2011 01:25:35 EDT

I want to sort the rows by date but this date format is not letting me do it. I have tried `Date_FORMAT` AND `STR_TO_DATE` function but couldn't get it working, could you please help me solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've modified your tables so you've got the original date field ('olddate') and want to put the reformatted 'native' date into a new field ('newdate'), then:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET newdate = STR_TO_DATE(olddate, '%a, %e %b %Y %H:%i:%s')
```

however, MySQL does not store timezone information in its date/time fields, so you'd have to convert the EDT stuff to whatever TZ is desired (UTC?).

Once converted to native format, you'd do your sorting with:

```
SELECT ...
...
ORDER BY YEAR(newdate)
```

Comment: i made a query just by using the mysql STR_TO_DATE function and it really worked. thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

This format is just plain text to MySQL and you should have another one as `datetime` or `timestamp` with the same data but something that MySQL could understand.

1. add a new column
2. use PHP to `strtotime` your actual row and replicate that value to the new column.
3. …
4. profit!